# Error en xsd dian colombia

Tags: java, xml, xsd

estoy intentando generar las clases de los xsd que proporciona la dian en java con netbeans utilizando la herramienta de jaxbinding, pero a la hora de hacerlo me genera los siguientes errores,

```
[ERROR] 'AcceptedIndicator' is already defined
  línea 21 de file:///C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion%20Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  línea 21 de file:/C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion%20Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd
```

Practicamente todos los componentes del archivo CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd dice que se repiten, este es el archivo xml que estoy intentando transformar :

en el archivo DIAN_UBL.xsd hace los siguientes imports

```
 <import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" schemaLocation="C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" schemaLocation="C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facturacion Electronica/XSD/UBL2/common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/Structures" schemaLocation="DIAN_UBL_Structures.xsd"/>
```

En el acuerto import, en el archivo DIAN_UBL_Structures.xsd hace los siguientes imports

```
 <import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" schemaLocation="xmldsig-core-schema.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" schemaLocation="http://www.dian.gov.co/micrositios/fac_electronica/documentos/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="http://www.dian.gov.co/micrositios/fac_electronica/documentos/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
```

Cuando quito el import que se está (UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd) repitiendo, mesaca otro error que dice que le falta ese import para que los tag sean validos.

Alguna ayuda? Se los agradecería mucho.

Comment: Hola, te hago una pregunta y disculpa que no pueda aportar mucho a tu pregunta pero, ¿qué tan avanzado estás con lo de la facturación electrónica de la DIAN ?

Comment: Hola, no te preocupes. Actualmente tengo en "funcionamiento" el servicio web que ellos proporcionan, solo que me devuelve comentarios de error ya que no he hecho la generacion de la factura electronica en xml, que es lo que estoy intentando para ya poder hacer las pruebas. Si necesitas ayuda en algo, puedes decirme.

Comment: Uy, si sería de gran ayuda, porque tengo un sistema que estoy desarrollando para mi empresa, en el cual tengo que implementar el tema de la facturación electrónica. Y poco he leído al respecto...jaja

Comment: Te recomiendo que empieces buscando las estructuras de las peticiones los servicios web soap y sus cacebecera y sobre wsse security

Comment: para DIAN_UBL_Structures.xsd no me funciono la solución dada, consulta, en la carpeta vienen dos versiones r0 y r1 cual se debe usar?

Answer (score 2):

esto lo puede solucionar cambiando las siguientes lineas

En el archivo DIAN_UBL.xsd los siguientes imports

```
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="../UBL2/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" schemaLocation="../UBL2/common/UBL-CommonBasicComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" schemaLocation="../UBL2/common/UBL-CommonExtensionComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
<import namespace="http://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/v1/Structures" schemaLocation="DIAN_UBL_Structures.xsd"/>
```

y en el DIAN_UBL_Structures.xsd

```
  <import namespace="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:specification:UnqualifiedDataTypesSchemaModule:2" schemaLocation="../UBL2/common/UnqualifiedDataTypeSchemaModule-2.0.xsd"/>
  <import namespace="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" schemaLocation="../UBL2/common/UBL-CommonAggregateComponents-2.0.xsd"/>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! Me sirvio, lo que cambia las referencias de las direcciones jajaja.